# Principal value with non-analytic function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can the principal value integral $$PV\int_{-1}^{2} \frac{\log{x}}{x} \ dx$$be defined? The definition involving contour integration clearly doesn't work, but what about the 'recipe' involving taking the limit as you approach the singularity?

Presumably you have to somehow define the logarithm on the negative real axis. I imagine we'll want to make sure that our definition is consistent with the real logarithm on the positive side, but I'm not well-versed enough to know if a full definition can be consistently given.

Considering a second case, is $$\int_{0}^{3} \frac{\log{x}}{x-2} \ dx $$ any better? Here we avoid questions about the log on the negative real axis, but it still has a branch point at $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition,
$$
\begin{align}
&\mathrm{PV}\int_{-1}^2\frac{\log(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left(\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}\frac{\log(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
+\int_\epsilon^2\frac{\log(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left(\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}\frac{i\pi}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
+\color{#C00000}{\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}\frac{\log|x|}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
+\int_\epsilon^1\frac{\log|x|}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}
+\int_1^2\frac{\log|x|}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=\left(\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}\frac{i\pi}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)
+\int_1^2\frac{\log(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=i\pi\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\log(\epsilon)
+\int_1^2\frac{\log(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-i\infty+\frac12\log(2)^2
\end{align}
$$
So the Principal Value would exist if only the $i\pi$ were not in the $\log(x)$ for $x\lt0$. With this in mind, and mimicking the proof above, we get that
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{PV}\int_{-1}^2\frac{\log|x|}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_1^2\frac{\log(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac12\log(2)^2
\end{align}
$$

---

For the second case
$$
\begin{align}
&\mathrm{PV}\int_0^3\frac{\log(x)}{x-2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\mathrm{PV}\int_0^3\left(\frac{\log(x)}{x-2}+\frac{\log(x)}{2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
-\int_0^3\frac{\log(x)}{2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\mathrm{PV}\int_0^3\frac{x\log(x)}{2(x-2)}\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac32\Big(\log(3)-1\Big)\tag{2}\\
&=\mathrm{PV}\int_0^3\frac{2\log(2)}{2(x-2)}\,\mathrm{d}x
+\int_0^3\frac{x\log(x)-2\log(2)}{2(x-2)}\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac32\Big(\log(3)-1\Big)\tag{3}\\
&=\small\mathrm{PV}\int_1^3\frac{\log(2)}{x-2}\,\mathrm{d}x
+\int_0^1\frac{\log(2)}{x-2}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^3\frac{x\log(x)-2\log(2)}{2(x-2)}\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac32\Big(\log(3)-1\Big)\tag{4}\\
&=\small\mathrm{PV}\int_{-1}^1\frac{\log(2)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
+\int_0^1\frac{\log(2)}{x-2}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^3\frac{x\log(x)-2\log(2)}{2(x-2)}\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac32\Big(\log(3)-1\Big)\tag{5}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\log(2)}{x-2}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^3\frac{x\log(x)-2\log(2)}{2(x-2)}\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac32\Big(\log(3)-1\Big)\tag{6}\\
&=-\log(2)^2+\int_0^3\frac{x\log(x)-2\log(2)}{2(x-2)}\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac32\Big(\log(3)-1\Big)\tag{7}\\
\end{align}
$$
where the integrand is a bounded function over a finite interval.

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{PV}\int_{-1}^1\frac{2\log(2)}{2x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left(\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}\frac{2\log(2)}{2x}\,\mathrm{d}x
+\int_\epsilon^1\frac{2\log(2)}{2x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}0\\
&=0\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
Motivation:

$(1)$: remove the possible problem of integrating $\log(x)$ near $0$
$(2)$: algebra and integration
$(3)$: move the singularity to an easier to handle form, away from the logs
$(4)$: break out the symmetric part around the singularity
$(5)$: change variables $x\mapsto x+2$
$(6)$: apply $(8)$
$(7)$: integration

Answer (score 1):

Up to [the definition of CPV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value),
$$PV\int_{-1}^{2} \frac{\log{x}}{x} \ dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0+}\left(\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon} \frac{\log{x}}{x} \ dx +\int_{\epsilon}^{2} \frac{\log{x}}{x} \ dx \right)$$ as the principal value of $\log(x)$ has a singularity at $x=0$. Because for $x<0$ the principal value of $\log(x)=\log|x|+\pi i$, the  limit under consideration  does not exist: consider the integral of  $i\pi/x$ over $(-1,-\epsilon)$. The one also may be treated as $\infty$. Next, up to Maple, $$ int(ln(z)/(z-2), z = 0 .. 3, CauchyPrincipalValue) $$ produces $$1/6\,{\pi }^{2}- \left( \ln  \left( 2 \right)  \right) ^{2}-{\it dilog
} \left( 3/2 \right)
  .$$ See [dilog](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=dilog) for info.

Comment: I remain unconvinced. Of course I knew the definition of the CPV when I asked the question. I am wondering whether this definition remains consistent when you have non-analytic functions. Of course you can use the 'recipe' as you did to try and generate a value, but whether it has the same meaning is unclear to me. Also, I don't understand what you mean the principal value of $\log{x}$ has a singularity at 0. The function is unbounded here, but this singularity is integrable.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious here, but the integral of $i \pi$ over $ (-1,-\epsilon$ seems totally unproblematic to me. Further, you can put that second integral into Maple (and I put it into Mathematica) and it spits out an answer, but should I trust it? CASs are stupid; they exactly do what you tell them to do, even if its i'll defined.

Comment: @ Kevin Driscoll: You wrote:"Further, you can put that second integral into Maple (and I put it into Mathematica) and it spits out an answer, but should I trust it?". Of course, this calculation can be done by hand too. This is a routine which is mechanized. If two CASes produce the same result, it seems to be reliable.

Comment: I didn't mean to question the computational skill of the CAS. What I mean is that the Cauchy Principal Value assigns a unique finite value to otherwise divergent integrals. We can use the same recipe here and get a value, but it is not clear to me that it has the property that its the unique finite value associated with that integral. My question is precisely about the applicability of the standard definition.

Answer (score 0):

The complex logarithm changes its value when you evaluate the function at the negative real line. Consider the familiar expression $$z=re^{i\theta}$$
Taking the logarithm on both sides give you $\log[z]=\log[r]+i(\theta+2n\pi)$. Therefore if $z$ is negative, $\theta\ge \frac{\pi}{2}$, and the imaginary part is not really well defined unless you want the principal value to be $$\log[r]+\pi i$$instead. If you defined it this way, then integrating $\frac{\log[r]}{r}$ from $-2$ to $3$ is no different from integrating $\int^{2}_{0}\frac{\log[r]}{r}+\int^{3}_{0}\frac{\log[r]}{r}+2\pi i$, where the first two are real valued integrals. But I think $\int^{2}_{0}\frac{\log[r]}{r}$ cannot be well defined, as one has to define it by 
$$\frac{1}{2}\log[r]^{2}|^{2}_{\epsilon}$$
which clearly diverges. Since the two integrals add up instead of cancelling each other at the singularity, we cannot compute the "principal value" as you desired.

The computation is at [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5Blog%5Bx%5D%2Fx%2C+%7Bx%2C-1%2C1%7D%5D).